# Responsive fixed width 3 column layout with full width drawer in Desktop and Mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a 3 column tile responsive design that's 1 column in mobile and 3 columns in desktop and each tile has a content drawer that needs to stretch the FULL width of the screen (complete with blue background).

I have a working model in a pen below but can't get the drawers to stretch full width?

Not sure if it's CSS or if there's a more optimum  HTML layout as doing the mobile first design and it works, just not in Desktop/wider views.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/trevcis/pen/ZMNNQW):

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
function openDrawer(tile) {

    var drawer = $(tile).attr("drawer");

    if ( $(tile).hasClass("ESGActive") ){ // Already is active?
         $(".ESGTile").removeClass("ESGActive");
         $("#" + drawer).slideUp();
    } else {
      // Get all tiles with class="ESGActive" and remove it
      $(".ESGTile").removeClass("ESGActive");

      // Get all elements with class="ESGDrawer" and hide them
      $(".ESGDrawer").slideUp();

      // Show the current tab drawer, add "active" class to the button
      $("#" + drawer).slideDown();
      $(tile).addClass("ESGActive");a
    }
}
```

```css
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
.ESGTiles > div{
  display:inline;
  padding:0;
}
.ESGDrawer {
  float:left;
  margin:0;
}
.ESGTile > img{
   display:none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
   .ESGTile > img, .FAQTile > img {
      display:block;
   }

   .ESGTiles > div{
     padding:15px;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
 .ESGDrawer {
  margin-top: 0!important;
  padding: 2em 0!important;
 }
 
 .FAQTile img, .ESGDrawer img {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .ESGTile, .FAQTile {
  margin: 0.2em 0;
 }
 
span.drawerToggle {
    position: relative;
    width: 24px!important;
    height: 24px!important;
    float:right;
}

.call-to-action img {
width: 70%;
margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
}
 
}

.FAQTile {
 background: #36872a!important;
 width: 100%;
}

.drawerToggle{
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float:right;
}
.drawerToggle:before, .drawerToggle:after{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        background-color: white;
        transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
 }

.drawerToggle:before{
        top: -1px;
        left: 50%;
        width: 2px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -1px;
 }

.drawerToggle:after{
        top: 50%;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2px;
        margin-top: -2px;
  }
    
/**.ESGTile:hover .drawerToggle:before{ transform: rotate(90deg); } 
.ESGTile:hover .drawerToggle:after{ transform: rotate(180deg); }**/
   
.ESGActive .drawerToggle:before{ transform: rotate(90deg); } 
.ESGActive .drawerToggle:after{ transform: rotate(180deg); }





.ESGTile, .FAQTile {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #1f335a;
 color: #fff;
 z-index: 100;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.ESGTile h3, .FAQTile h3 {
 color: #fff;
}

.ESGTile:hover {
 background-color: #344794;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.FAQTile:hover {
 background-color: #00a651!important;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.ESGActive {
 background: #344794;
}

.ESGActive:after {
 bottom: -3px;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 120;
 pointer-events: none;
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-left: -10px;
}

.ESGTile h3, .FAQTile h3 {
 font-size: 1.2em;
}


.ESGLabel, .FAQLabel {
 margin: 0;
 display: block;
 padding: 0.8em 15px;
}

.ESGDrawer {
 display: none;
 background: #1f335a;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 4em 0;
 margin-top: 0.3em;
 z-index: 90;
 position:inline-block;
 width:100vw;
 left:0;
}

.ESGDrawer h4 {
 font-size: 1.8em;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.ESGDrawer p {
 line-height: 1.4em;
}

.ESGDrawer p.cta-wrapper {
 margin: 0.3em 0 0 0;
}

.ESGDrawer p.cta-wrapper a:before {
 bottom: 0;
}

.ESGDrawer a:link, .ESGDrawer a:hover, .ESGDrawer a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}

hr {
 display: none;
}

.call-to-action {
padding: 3em 0;
}

footer {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">

  
  <!-- TILE 1 *********************** -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   
   <!-- Tile --> 
   <a class="ESGTile" onclick="openDrawer(this)" drawer="title-1">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kamunga.com/test.jpg" height="360" width="640">
    <h3 class="ESGLabel">Title 1<span class="drawerToggle"></span></h3>
   </a>
 
   <!-- Drawer -->
   <div id="title-1" class="container-fluid ESGDrawer"> 
    <div class="container ESGMiddleDrawerContent">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       <h4>Title 1</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


  <!-- TILE 2 *********************** -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   
   <!-- Tile --> 
   <a class="ESGTile" onclick="openDrawer(this)" drawer="title-2">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kamunga.com/test.jpg" height="360" width="640">
    <h3 class="ESGLabel">Title 2<span class="drawerToggle"></span></h3>
   </a>
 
   <!-- Drawer -->
   <div id="title-2" class="container-fluid ESGDrawer"> 
    <div class="container ESGMiddleDrawerContent">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       <h4>Title 2</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>  
  
  <!-- TILE 3 *********************** -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
   
   <!-- Tile --> 
   <a class="ESGTile" onclick="openDrawer(this)" drawer="title-3">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.kamunga.com/test.jpg" height="360" width="640">
    <h3 class="ESGLabel">Title 3<span class="drawerToggle"></span></h3>
   </a>
 
   <!-- Drawer -->
   <div id="title-3" class="container-fluid ESGDrawer"> 
    <div class="container ESGMiddleDrawerContent">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
       <h4>Title 3</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>  
  
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want it  full width of the whole page or the while col?

Comment: The blue drawers (class of ESGDrawer) needs to be full width of the browser so the content would be fixed width to match the tiles width but the overall blue width would be across the full browser window.  Hopefully that's a little clearer??

Comment: Something like this? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/XVdVmg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're
I added this code at the end of the CSS

```
.body {
    position: relative;
}
.ESGDrawer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 247px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.x{

    position: inherit;
}
```

and I add a new classname to each of your `col-xs-12 col-md-4` divs

Check the working demo here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JaQPjN

Comment: SOO close.      It doesn't work for mobile but wrapping the new .ESGDrawer in a media statement easily fixes that issue so thanks.

I think the issue is that it doesn't push content so other content on the page won't necessarily work and not sure if it's as simple as z-indexes.

The design actually has two rows and when I put that in you can see what I mean:   https://codepen.io/trevcis/pen/ZMNNQW